# How to get (2R,3R)-2,3-dibromobutane from but-2-yne?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, stereochemistry, halides

What I had in mind was to form but-2-ene with $\ce{H2}$ and Lindlar's catalyst and then simply add bromine ($\ce{Br2}$). But this addition, if I'm not mistaken, is a trans-addition. So I would end up with (2*R*,3*S*)-2,3-dibromobutane instead of (2*R*,3*R*).

Note that this is (2*R*,3*S*)-2,3-dibromobutane:

[image: (2R,3S)-2,3-dibromobutane]

Have I made a mistake, or is there something wrong in my way of thinking? If my solution is wrong, how could I get (2*R*,3*R*)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Lindlar is a cis-addition so one would not obtain a (2*R*,3*S*), but rather (2*S*,3*S*) and (2*R*,3*R*) which happen to be enantiomers.

Comment: Yes, pretty much. And if you wanted the other diastereomer (the (2R,3S) i.e. meso diastereomer), you would just need to use Na, NH3 to reduce the alkyne first. That gives the *trans* alkene which adds Br2 in an *anti* fashion (via the bromonium ion) to give the meso compound.